# Satisfying the inequality of a bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hi I am having an issue of proving this inequality.

The problem:

Suppose: $G(x) = |x|^2 + 1$

Show: $\left|\frac{d}{dx}G(x)\right| \leq cG$ (A bounded derivative)

My initial attempt would use the lipschitz (or Gronwalls Lemma?) However, I am unsure how to finish the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we know that 
$$ |\frac{d}{dx} G(x)| = |2x| = 2|x|$$
but when $x \geq 1$ you know that  $|x| \leq |x|^2$, moreover this implies that  it is always true that $|x| \leq |x|^2 +1$  but we know that $ \frac{1}{c}|\frac{d}{dx} G(x)| =  |x|$ ( in our case the constant $1/c =1/2$), so from this we get:

$$ \frac{1}{c}  |\frac{d}{dx} G(x)| = |x| \leq x^2+1 = G(x)$$
$$ \rightarrow  |\frac{d}{dx} G(x)| \leq c G(x) $$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, theres something I am not quite understanding (its late here.) How does 1/c * |dG/dx| =|x|?  THank you for the help.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: |dG/dx| = |x| because |dG/dx| / 2 = 2|x|/2 (both sides?)

Comment: @JinYU your welcome. remember $|dG/dx| = 2|x|$, so just divide by 2 on each side and you get $|dG/dx|*(1/2) = |x|$, I just replaced 2 with $c$ to make the point...

Comment: @JinYu Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark if an answer solves your problem.

Comment: Hi I am quite new to this.  I cannot find the check box (as I want to give you credit for helping.)  Thanks!